# what is the difference between img.height vs img.style.height?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-canvas

I am trying to resize a bunch of images by going through an array and resizing them

```
if(items[0].height > 700 || items[0].width > 700){
  items[0].style.height = "700px";
   items[0].style.width = "700px";
}
```

When I am playing with canvas trying to crop images I notice that that coordinates I give it to crop aren't cutting what I would expect.

I am going assume that img.style.height only changes display properties and img.height changes the actual dimensions of the img? or do they do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img.height` refers to the height attribute on the element, `img.style.height` refers to the height defined as a style (like in css)

for

`img.height` will be 20.

for

```
<img id="example" style="height:20">
```

`img.style.height` will be 20.  If you're setting the style generally its better to prefer using styles and separating out your concerns over hardcoding the heights as attributes.  So in this case probably set a class on the image and put the height in CSS.

If you're reading the styles, `img.height` will return the actual height no matter how its set, so its safer.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference I've found (other than the nature of the attribute as described by @ben336) is in what they can represent.

- **img.height** will always represent the height in *pixels.* This is only true in HTML5, which is what I'm guessing you're using based on your tags. Earlier versions of HTML allow both percentage and pixels to be specified by img.height, making my point moot.

  ```
  img.height = 20; // Always means 20 pixels.
  ```
- **img.style.height** on the other hand will represent the height either in *pixels* or as a *percentage* of the original size.

  ```
  img.style.height = 20px; // 20 pixels in height;
  ```

  or

  ```
  img.style.height = 20%; // 20% of original height.
  ```